# How can I get audio from AVISplitter output pin into a MemoryStream in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I'm creating an application in C#,using DirectShow.NET for playing an .avi file. I need to create an audio waveform for the audio track/s present in the .avi file.

How can I get the data from the output pin into a MemoryStream ? 
Or does any one know of any controls/filters that could generate audio waveforms from DirectShow audio filters.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a standard pipeline the controlling application is not supposed to even have direct access to data, so you have to do one of the following:

- add Sample Grabber, grab data and create thee timeline in code
- use specialized filter to grab the data for you and preprocess it to give you timeline or data which you can build the timeline from